# How can I count the number of weekdays between two dates, considering Saturday a weekday?

Tags: date, sas, date-difference

I have a dataset with the first and the last day of an event. I need to calculate the number of weekdays between the two dates. However, I need to consider Saturday as a weekday. How can I do that?

This is the example which is exactly like my dataset, but smaller. I've been using it to test the code before running everything:

```
data testing_weekdays;
    input id $ date_1 date9. id2 $ dat2_2 date9.;
    format date_1 date9. dat2_2 date9.;
    datalines;
AA 01jan2019 AA 25jan2019
BB 02feb2019 BB 12feb2019
CC 10aug1990 CC 05jan1995
DD 11dec1999 DD 21dec1999
;
run;
```

When I use the intck function with the parameter 'weekday', I get the difference considering both Saturday and Sunday as weekend. But I would like to consider only Sunday.

I saw this solution on SAS community: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Sunday-to-Saturday-work-day/td-p/338412, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Are you asking how to count how many Sundays are between two dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sas function intck to find required interval. in your example, following will be the statement:

```
data want;
 set testing_weekdays;
 wkdays=intck('WEEKDAY1W',date_1,dat2_2);
run;
```

You can use different formats for Weekday interval. The days are numbered as Sunday(1) .. Saturday(7). So if you want to keep Sunday as a weekend, then WEEKDAY1W is used as interval.. Say if you want Monday(2), Wed(4) as weekends, then use- WEEKDAY24W

Answer (score 0):

```
 data new;
 set old
 interval=intck('weekday1w',begin,end);
 run;
```